# Access previous entity on update operations

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm looking for the most idiomatic way to inspect what changes are being made during an update operation through an entity chain managed by Spring Data Rest.

My current use case is that I want to update the last time a password was modified. My domain object has two fields, a password and a modification time. I want my REST api to just have to set the password and I will detect if its a new one and update the modification time. I would prefer to not have my frontend know if it has to set the modification time. I would also prefer to not create a database trigger.

I have tried creating a `HandleBeforeSave` event that tries to query the existing domain object and compare it to the one passed into the event handler. Unfortunately they are the exact same object so I can't detect the difference between them. I have tried doing the query through both the Spring Data repository and through an `EntityManager`. I'm using Hibernate 5 as my backend.

When stepping through the `patchItemResource` method on `RepositoryEntityController`, the result of `payload.getContent()` reflects the entire entity, even if I only patched one field, with the updates applied. I can't tell if this is done by Jackson or if the `PersistentEntityResource` is handling it somewhere. If anyone knows the code flow that does the object merging that would be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is to use an Entity Lifecycle listener to store a reference to the previous state on Entity load and implement a second listener to modify other fields on update.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Events

```
 @Entity
 public class SomeEntity{

        @Transient
        private SomeEntity previousState;

        @PostLoad
        private void storeState(){
          previousState = new SomeEntity();
          previousState.setPassword(this.getPassword());  
        }

        @PreUpdate
        private void doBeforeUpdate(){
            if(!previousState.getPassword().equals(this.getPassword()){
                //update time.  
            }
        }
    }
```